# Can't connect through PHP to an Access Database

Tags: php, ms-access, connection-string

I have to establish a connection via PHP to a Access Database, but everytime I try I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception'

With message:

> '**Source:** Microsoft OLE DB
>   Service Components
> **Description:** Das Format der Initialisierungszeichenfolge entspricht nicht 
>       den OLE DB-Angaben.' in E:\path\to\phpfile.php:93
>   Stack trace:  #0  E:\path\to\phpfile.php(93): com->Open('DRIVER={Microso...') #1 {main} thrown in

The German text means something like "the format of the initialization string is not common of the OLE DB statements.

My connection code looks like

```
$db = 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("\") & ("\\db\\db.mdb") & ";"';
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection"); 
$conn->Open($db);
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. In pure ASP it works fine, but not in PHP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe consider using this instead of COM?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php   - Also some good general comments on that page re. connecting to Access.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the "ADODB.Connection" module use PDO since it's currently the best option out there and is a best practice, Here is the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

But if PDO isn't for you then see ODBC (PDO RECOMMENDED) which is a native PHP module. Here is the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php
To start a connection you would do this:  `$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $user, $password);`

Comment: thanks for the reply but it doesnt work. but code looks like `$dbpath = 'Server.MapPath("//") & ("//db//seilbahn.mdb")';
$db = odbc_connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbpath", "", "");` but it runs with an error which says " [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid Filename" ... but the File IS there (same name etc.).

Comment: ok. i have done the "quick & dirty" way. i redirect to an .asp file which establish the connection and inserts my GET variables into the db. but thanks for your patience and answers!

Answer (score 1):

Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. It can connect via ODBC:

```
$pathToMDB = "path/to/db.mdb";
$db = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$pathToMDB", 'admin');
```